# Irregular line spacing in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

The line spacing (or line height?) in my Table of Contents is irregular, see image below.

For example: the vertical gap between 1-1-1 and 1-1-2 is larger than that between 1-1-2 and 1-1-3.

As @ChristianHupfer suggested in the comments; when a line contains a letter with a descender such as 'p' or 'y', more vertical space is claimed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

The example above can be produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright]{book}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Changes to the default book class style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
%
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }%
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\listfigurename}%
              {\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }%
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \listtablename}%
         {\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }%
\makeatother
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Definitions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcommand*{\loflotintoc}[1]%
            {\def\loflot_in_toc{#1}}
%
\loflotintoc{}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Fancy Chapter Headings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\RequirePackage{fncychap}
%
\makeatletter
  \ChNameVar{\raggedleft\Huge\rm}
  \ChNumVar{\Huge\rm}
  \ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Huge\sf\bfseries}
  \ChRuleWidth{2pt}

  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
   }
  \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 60\p@
    }
  \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 60\p@
    }
\makeatother
%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Change format TOC, sections, subsections, etc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\renewcommand\thesection      {\thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection-\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection-\arabic{paragraph}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph-\arabic{subparagraph}}
\renewcommand\thefigure       {\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable        {\thechapter-\arabic{table}}
%
\makeatletter
%
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\sffamily\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \sffamily
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
%
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \sffamily
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
%
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries \sffamily #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
%
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries \sffamily
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
%
\renewcommand*\l@section{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\sffamily \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
%
\makeatother
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    HyperReference
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\RequirePackage[hyperref]{xcolor}
\ifpdf
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\else
  \RequirePackage{pstricks,pst-node}
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\fi
%
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.3,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkbrown}{rgb}{0.28,0.07,0.07}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Extra Packages and Options
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\RequirePackage[headheight=14.6pt,hmarginratio=1:1,top=3.5cm,height=22.5cm,width=14.9cm,headsep=1.0cm,footskip=1.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
%
\RequirePackage{psfrag}
%
\RequirePackage[notintoc]{nomencl}[2005/09/22]
%
% separate paragraphs instead of indenting them
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%
% small sans-serif font family for captions
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\small\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
%
% better vertical spacing in tables
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
%
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Header Definition
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
% Headers and footers for plain (blank) pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  %\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries \thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily \bfseries \thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    TOC / LOF / LOT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcommand{\toc}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents\cleardoublepage
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
}
%
\newcommand{\toclof}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents\cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\loflot_in_toc}{0} }{\cleardoublepage}{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listfigurename}\cleardoublepage%
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\cleardoublepage%
    }%
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
}
%
\newcommand{\tocloflot}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
    \tableofcontents\cleardoublepage%
    \listoffigures%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\loflot_in_toc}{0} }{\cleardoublepage}{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listfigurename}\cleardoublepage%
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\cleardoublepage%
    }%
    \listoftables%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\loflot_in_toc}{0} }{\cleardoublepage}{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\listtablename}\cleardoublepage%
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}\cleardoublepage%
    }%
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}%
    \cleardoublepage
}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\begin{document}%

% Front matter
\frontmatter

\loflotintoc{1} % 1 = include LOF and LOT in TOC
\tocloflot

% Main matter
\mainmatter

\chapter{Example Chapter}
\section{Section without descender}
\subsection{Subsection with descender, such as p or y}
\subsection{Subsection without descender}
\subsection{Subsection without descender}
\section{Section without descender}
\section{Section with descender, such as p or y}
\section{Section with descender, such as p or y}
\section{Section without descender}
\section{Section without descender}

\appendix

% Back matter
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Simulation Set-Up` has a descender in `p`, so there is more vertical space between the first two entries

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) can we get some (full) code that generates this. (3) Have you verified that this is not a bug in the viewer used by sharelatex? The build in PDF viewers in browsers are known to have issues from time to time.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see. So line-spacing is regular, but the line-height is not? Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: @daleif (1) Thank you :) (2) I've added some code (3) Yes, I've exported to PDF and found the same issue.

Comment: the output you show isn't standard but you have not provided any code that anyone can run to debug the issue. Please fix example code so that it produces the spacing shown. For example   I assume 6-1  is section 1 in chapter 6 (so generated by l@section ? This would be obvious if we could run the example....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, you're right. I've added extra code. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what you say is true but it should never happen (and was due to code not shown originally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I wondered actually about the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
```

which tells latex to try to fit the lines into half the normal height which is less than the size of the letters, so it has no possibility of maintaining the specified baseline spacing. In such cases rather than try to maintain even space it just stacks the lines one above the other, with `\lineskip` (1pt) in between, so the space between lines depends on the size of the characters in the line.

Comment: This works, thanks! I've set `{0.5\baselineskip}` to `{0.8\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @Wouter That is almost as bad!! the default linespacing at 11pt is 13.5pt so .8 of that is 10.9pt which is still _less_ than than size of the letters. Just remove the lines completely.